# showing a category specified field after clicking radio button

Tags: html, vue.js

here I have written a code for multistep form with radio button. So here in a first step I have a category field where user enters a category and based on that category we are prompting the next field.
So here while user enters a category after that radio button form will display. if radio button is checked also we need to prompt a form whatever category entered in first step. Simply if user enters category then next step is radio button form if we checked the radio button then next form should display based on the entered category in first step

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.0.4/dist/vue.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
  <form>
<!--here is a first step where user enters a category and based on that category we need to prompt other template which is inside aa step two-->
  <div v-if="step === 1">

    <h1>Step One</h1>
    <p>
    <legend for="name">Your Name:</legend>
    <input id="name" name="name" v-model="category">
    </p>

    <button @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>

  </div>


<!--here we have step two div inside this div we have radio button template, so if user enters any category in first step -->
<!--and users click on radio button then based on category we need to prompt other template-->
  <div v-if="step === 2">
      {% if user_type == 'business' %}
      <template>
          <input type="radio">
        <button @click.prevent="prev()">Previous</button>
        <button @click.prevent="submit()">Save</button>
      </template>

      {% else %}
<!--this template is based on category laptop-->
      <template v-if="category == 'laptop'">
       <h1>template laptop</h1>
        <button @click.prevent="prev()">Previous</button>
        <button @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>
      </template>
<!--this template is based on category IT-->
      <template v-if="category == 'IT'">
       <h1>template IT</h1>
        <button @click.prevent="prev()">Previous</button>
        <button @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>
      </template>
<!--this template is based on category computer-->
      <template v-if="category == 'computer'">
       <h1>template computer</h1>
        <button @click.prevent="prev()">Previous</button>
        <button @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>
      </template>
  </div>
{% endif %}
<!--here is third step div after category specified field is prompted then in next step we are prompting this div-->
  <div v-if="step === 3">
    <h1>Step Three</h1>

    <button @click.prevent="prev()">Previous</button>
    <button @click.prevent="submit()">Save</button>

  </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
```

`vue.js`

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data() {
    return {
      step:1,
        category:null,
        street:null,
        city:null,
        state:null,
        numtickets:0,
        shirtsize:'XL'
    }
  },
  methods:{
    prev() {
      this.step--;
    },
    next() {
      this.step++;
    },
    submit() {
      alert('Submit to blah and show blah and etc.');
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi,
It is woking fine, If I enter IT in the first step then if I select a radio button and click next then I am moved to the step 3.

Comment: step 3 means based on "it" template should display. In my case I have written django condition so it is not working

Comment: Hi. will you please suggest me how to use django condition in vue.js because if I am giving this condition  "{% if user_type == 'business' %}" Then it is prompting category based template. Please help me if you have an idea